# MVC native way to form url from text inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In ASP.NET MVC i have a route `/search/{what}/{where}/{pagenr}/`

And on my homepage i have 2 text inputs, in which i want the user to type something like:

> text1: apples text2: spain.

If i use FormMethod.Post, this works fine, but i dont get the correct Url. I just get /search.
In some other post someone mentioned to use FormMethod.Get, but then i get my posted values in querystring form, which is not what i want.

Can anyone tell me how i go from that input form, to the url that matches my route?

Of course i can do that with javascript. But i was thinking that there should be a better, MVC way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to use javascript you will need to do your regular http post and then redirect inside your action

```
return RedirectToAction("Search", new { What = "..", Where = "..", Pagenr = ".." });
```

Mind you, if your using ajax forms this wont work and i would recommend doing a javascript navigation.

Comment: Thanks. That was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format), GET forms **have** to use query strings (starts with `?` and separated with `&`).

The only way to transform query strings to url segment is JavaScript.

Or you can just forget the segment built route.